# Does estimated fixed effects change if we change reference level?

Tags: econometrics, fixed-effects-model, identifiability

Consider a fixed effect model $$y_{it}=x_{it}'\beta+\alpha_{i}+\epsilon_{it}$$
To estimate the fixed effects $\alpha_i$ we can add a dummy for each individual and run the least-squares dummy variables regression. We will need to omit one individual dummy because of co-linearity. For the estimates of other $\alpha_i$, they are the estimated individual fixed effects. (Hope I am correct so far)

My question:

1. What about the fixed effect of the individual we omitted when estimating the regression? Is that zero?
2. Should I interpret the fixed effects of other individuals as relative values to the omitted individual?
3. If we change the reference level (omit different individuals when estimating the coefficients), will the result (estimated fixed effects and other coefficients) change? If so, how should we choose the reference level?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Your question is clear and to the point. The individual effects are often treated as nuisance. Do you particularly care about the estimates of the individual (fixed) effects?

Comment: Hi @ThomasBilach , yes! The motivation for this is that I want to take out the fixed effects and do analysis based on those fixed effects. (For example, I may want to run a cross section regression where each observation is an individual i)

Comment: What software are you using to fit your model? Do you have any other categorical variables in your model?

Comment: Hi @DimitriyV.Masterov I am using Stata (using reg command and factor notation). There are no other categorical variables except for this fixed effect. Could you explain why those two issues matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force Stata to exclude an intercept with

- using ibn. prefix for the id variable (no base level)
- using noconstant option

This means that everyone gets their own FEs and no one is dropped. If you had other categorical variable in your model, this becomes impossible.

The alternative is that the omitted individual gets the intercept as his FE, and everyone else gets the intercept plus their own FE. This is what Stata will do by default.

It does not matter whom you drop. The dummy variable coefficients will change, but not the actual value of the FE. The other coefficients should stay the same.

The FEs are unbiased, but they are inconsistent, so don't take them too seriously at unit level. Their sample average, however, is a consistent estimator of the mean of the population distribution of heterogeneity. If you want to do a regression with the estimated FEs as the outcome, you can think of that regression as calculating a conditional mean, which may be OK.